# Spring Security MethodSecurityInterceptor

Tags: security, methods, spring-security

I've got an Java application running on tomcat6. 
I'm using spring 3.0.4 and spring security 3.0.5.

to protect the access of my dao methods i want to use the spring security `MethodSecurityInterceptor`. but this one doesn't actually "intercept" access at all.

It is configured like this:

```
<bean id="securityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor"> 

    <property name="authenticationManager"> 
        <ref bean="authenticationManager"/> 
    </property> 

    <property name="accessDecisionManager"> 
        <ref bean="accessDecisionManager"/> 
    </property> 

    <property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <value> 
            com.xkst.dao.InvoiceDao.*=ROLE_ADMIN
            com.xkst.dao.UserDao.*=ROLE_ADMIN
        </value>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

According to the configuration every access of any of the methods of the UserDao should be intercepted an controlled.

The methods to be protected get accessed by a rich client Java application. To make the service available for the client I use the spring `HttpInvokerServiceExporter`.

The dao classes are not exported directly. there is a single serviceclass being exported providing a single point of access for the client.

On the client side I've got this `clientContext.xml` file which references the exported service on the server.

In the client code I just load the context and pick the exported bean out of it

```
public class SecurityTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clientContext.xml");
    EntityServiceInterface serverService = (EntityServiceInterface) ctx.getBean("entityServiceInterface");

    List<UserEntity> users = serverService.performGetAllUsers();
    for(UserEntity user : users) {
        System.out.println(user.getUserName());
    }

}
```

here i can just invoke any method of the 'serverService' on my client which should be protected by the 'MethodSecurityInterceptor' without authenticating. I can query all data from my 'UserDao'.

I really don't know what the missing link is.

`authenticationManager` and `accessDecisionManager` are configured as well. there is no error message at the startup of the server. it even logs the creation of the "secured methods" like:

```
2011-08-01 10:38:48,675  INFO MethodDefinitionMap:75 - Adding secure method [public java.util.List com.xkst.dao.UserDao.findAll()] with attributes [[ROLE_ADMIN]]
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not quite sure anymore - but i guess the problem was to call methods within the same interface-implementation. The interceptor only works for method-calls from outside; another class. Spring creates a proxy object around the original object and handles the interception there as far as i understand. HTH (a little bit).

Comment: You just saved my day! I've been debugging spring for a day now to figure out why weren't my methods being authenticated when calling those, without realizing that annotation would only work when the spring method invoker could intervene, i.e. when addressing those from outside via spring...